# How to query mutiple nodes by ID, Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I had an object like this coming from firebase realtime database

```
  "3e97a0918fc5429ca470e017a9ff0b04": {
    "bearing": 0,
    "latitude": "19.9737038",
    "longitude": "73.7897944",
    "timestamp": "1557027317083",
    "trip": "3e97a0918fc5429ca470e017a9ff0b04",
    "user": "1346"
  },
  "43efa340444d454cb2673b9afd95c810": {
    "bearing": 329,
    "latitude": "20.1597784",
    "longitude": "73.8792233",
    "timestamp": "1554784486880",
    "trip": "43efa340444d454cb2673b9afd95c810",
    "user": "1339"
  },
  "4d1118279bd14597a59feaf883c1a1a4": {
    "bearing": 227,
    "latitude": "20.1588567",
    "longitude": "73.8851554",
    "timestamp": "1554681994097",
    "trip": "4d1118279bd14597a59feaf883c1a1a4",
    "user": "1467"
  },
  "4e28d129df8d4e399e094fd85f9891a0": {
    "bearing": 0,
    "latitude": "20.1450097",
    "longitude": "73.8935804",
    "timestamp": "1554940195655",
    "trip": "4e28d129df8d4e399e094fd85f9891a0",
    "user": "1488"
  },
  "584427ae15f240c896c13058e41a69b5": {
    "bearing": 177,
    "latitude": "20.1595356",
    "longitude": "73.8792819",
    "timestamp": "1554521339710",
    "trip": "584427ae15f240c896c13058e41a69b5",
    "user": "1316"
  },
  "5a4c13ed54584541b5da1fe6dc4d4405": {
    "bearing": 0,
    "latitude": "20.1597879",
    "longitude": "73.8792057",
    "timestamp": "1554523562777",
    "trip": "5a4c13ed54584541b5da1fe6dc4d4405",
    "user": "1511"
  },
}
```

But I want to only track trips with particular `IDS`. My Question is how do I limit the nodes by providing particular ids?

Let say I only wanted trips with ids

`3e97a0918fc5429ca470e017a9ff0b04`
`43efa340444d454cb2673b9afd95c810`

I tried using the `equalTo` method but that returns a single trip. And i also tried using orderByChild("trip") but that doesnt help either since the trips are uuids.

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to only track"? Do you mean setting a listener with the `on()` method? https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You write in your question that you want "to **track** trips". If you want to declare a listener for only a certain list of database nodes (i.e. `trips`) in order to listen to their changes (i.e. "tracking" them), you will need to call the [`on()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference.html#on) method for each node.

Something like the following would do the trick:

```
  var database = firebase.database();
  var idsToListenTo = ["3e97a0918fc5429ca470e017a9ff0b04", "3e97a0918fc5429ca470e017a9ff0b04"];

  idsToListenTo.forEach(id => {
        database.ref(id).on('value', snapshot => {
            console.log("trip " + snapshot.key + " has just changed");
            console.log(snapshot.val());
        });
    }
  );
```

Comment: I knew this. but i wanted to do it via a single listener. I guess there isnt a better way.. Thanks for responding though.. highly appreciated :)

Comment: Note that you could maybe consider the `child_changed` event type for the `on()` method, but it will be triggered for any child of a reference, therefore you would need to detect if the child key is part of the list of nodes you want to listen to (and you would generate unnecessary reads in case the key is not in the nodes list).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `and` query in firebase database. If you want to retrieve data according to the `id` then you can use the `equalTo()` method that will retrieve according to one single id. If you want multiple ids, then you will have to create an attribute that will contain the ids that you want to query on. For example:

```
  "584427ae15f240c896c13058e41a69b5": {
    "bearing": 177,
    "latitude": "20.1595356",
    "longitude": "73.8792819",
    "timestamp": "1554521339710",
    "trip": "584427ae15f240c896c13058e41a69b5",
    "user": "1316",
    "ids": "584427ae15f240c896c13058e41a69b5_3e97a0918fc5429ca470e017a9ff0b04"
  },
```

Then you can use `equalTo()` on the child `ids`.

Comment: A bad way to do it, since it involves changing the actual node. The data here comes from an android application, so changing it is not very flexible.

Comment: @Peter: I think OP is looking for a `WHERE id IN` type query, not an `AND` query as you are describing here.